# Debug not outputting content

Tags: debugging

We're trying to debug a site with multiple routing problems. We obviously need the debug profile to see what templates are being parsed and when. However, the results are not being shown on the front end.

We're of course logged in as superadmins.
We tried the debug toolbar too, but nothing shows up.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Santiago

Comment: Is this an MSM site?

Comment: Hi Derek. It's not an MSM site.

Comment: Is the template debugging config option set to Yes? Is it possibly being overridden by a config file? When using the EE debug toolbar, does it show up in the CP?

Comment: It's correctly setup and not overridden by config. Debug results have been coming and going randomly for the past three days. I'm thinking it might be something else, as we cloned the site on another server and it worked like a charm.